# GRANT文の実行時にエラー：ERROR 1064

Tags: mysql

**SQL文**

```
grant all privileges on *.* to test_user1@"%" identified by 'test1234' with grant option;
```

**エラーメッセージ**

```
ERROR 1064
```

SQLの文法に誤りがあるみたいなのですが、なにがちがいますか？

Comment: [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual :: 13.7.1.6 GRANT Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html) に記載されている GRANT 文のフォーマットを参照しますと、`priv_level` の指定に誤りがある事が判ります。

Comment: どう指定すればいいですか？

Answer (score 0):

おそらくユーザーを作成しようとしているのだと思うのですが、ユーザーを作成するには grant ではなく create user を使用します。grant は作成したユーザーに権限を付与するために使用します。

以前のバージョンの MySQL では grant でユーザーも作成されましたが、最近のバージョンではエラーになります。

次のようにすればいいと思います。

```
create user test_user1@'%' identified by 'test1234';
grant all on *.* to test_user1@'%' with grant option;
```

Comment: ありがとうございます -bash: grant: command not found が出てしまいます

Comment: bash ではなく mysql で実行してください。

Comment: test_user1@'IPアドレス'でログインしようとするとmax-join-size                     1000000
show-warnings                     FALSE
plugin-dir                        (No default value)
default-auth                      (No default value)
binary-mode                       FALSE
connect-expired-password          FALSE
compression-algorithms            (No default value)
zstd-compression-level            3
load-data-local-dir               (No default value)のような説明文が出ます

Comment: ユーザーは作成できて GRANT も成功したということでしょうか。であればこの質問については解決済みだと思うので、新しく質問をした方がいいと思います。なお、質問時には、どのような目的でどのような入力をするとどのような結果になったかといういのを明記すると回答が得られやすいと思います。

Comment: 作成はできて grant を しようとログインしようとすると エラーになります(というか説明文)

Comment: root で create user と grant をする必要があります。create user で作成したばかりのユーザーには何の権限もないので grant することもできません。説明文が出る件については「test_user1@'IPアドレス'でログインしようとする」で実行したコマンドを具体的に書いてください。